# Getting text from compiled directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a bunch of directives that are displaying text on page - there are ng-repeats etc. I have to provide searching method for user - user can search any text in this page. I can't get this text from another service - I have to compile this directive and get text from it.

I am getting text like that:

```
var elem =  $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($rootScope.$new(true));
result = $timeout(function(){return elem.html();}, 0);
```

And I get text from this, what does work, but it does not seem to be compiled:

```
<img class="flag" src="images/flags/{{ lang }}.svg" alt="{{ lang }}" />
```

What should I do in order to get content of the directive fully compiled?

Comment: It would be great to see your controller, of the $scope where you are including that image template. It seems quite complicated to me to see what is the connection.

Comment: I will include it tomorrow, but I've checked it in chrome dev tools and it seems like controller is called correctly - in my opinion, `elem.html()` is causing this trouble, but I don't really know, how should I get "content" of directive other way.

Comment: What I wanted to understand is why exactly you need the content of the directive itself, instead keep linked with Angular.

Comment: I need this, because directive generates "help chapter" content, which user can search through. There is really no point in gathering this data on server side, because I use `translate` on angular side - user should be able to find any word in text generated by that directive (it iterates through options etc.). It can as well one-binding everything, so I just want content of this directive, parsed and compiled to normal HTML page.